# How to use Multiple Flow Players in one page using PHP

Tags: php, javascript, flowplayer

The first video works fine but the rest just don't come up, URL to the videos are coming from a database. There could be multiple videos placed on a page where the URL is coming from the database. I Tried to place the javascript inside the "while Loop" but then nothing worked (or maybe i done something wrong)
Here is what i right now

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query12))

{                               
echo"<a  
href='$urls'
style='display:block;width:520px;height:330px' 
id='player'> 
</a> 
<br/>                           
<br/>";
}
```

This will install flowplayer inside previous A- tag.

```
<script>
flowplayer("player", {
src:"flowplayer-3.2.16.swf",
wmode: "opaque" // This allows the HTML to hide the flash content
}, {
clip: {
autoPlay: false
}
});
</script>
```

Comment: each player needs its one unique id

Comment: @Dagon How would i go about doing that?

Comment: the db must have an id per row, just use that

Comment: I have answered your original question, which is the same as this. http://stackoverflow.com/a/18465212/1593273